# What will be the eigen values of new matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A $ is any real symmetric matrix and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2...,\alpha_n$ are eigenvalues of $A$. We are constructing a new matrix $B$ whose diagonal enteries are twice the diagonal enteries of $A$ and rest enteries are same as of $A$. Then how to find eigen values of $B$.

I just know that $B = A+D$ & both $A$ and $B $ are diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee of what the eigenvalues of the sum will be.  However, we can bound the eigenvalues with, for example, [Weyl's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl.27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory).

Comment: actually I am trying to find out eigen values for a bigger matrix whose diagonal blocks are A+D and off digonal blocks are A-D. I am sure that $2\alpha_1,2\alpha_2,...2\alpha_n$ will be n e.v. for this matrix but how to find rest n?

Comment: What makes you so sure?

Comment: And how many blocks to the matrix you're actually looking at?

Comment: there are only two 4 blocs two on diagonal two off diagonal. And I am not sure just want to have any idea to proceed or to stop.

Comment: @Sry So maybe you should ask *that* question.